# Is Android license agreement the same as Android SDK license agreement?

Tags: android, sdk

I am looking for Android Agreement License but all I find is the SDK license. I wonder if they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Android SDK is the license you need to agree to.

> 1.1 The Android Software Development Kit (referred to in the License Agreement as the "SDK" and specifically including the Android system files, packaged APIs, and Google APIs add-ons) is licensed to you subject to the terms of the License Agreement. The License Agreement forms a legally binding contract between you and Google in relation to your use of the SDK.

For more information visit this link:
https://developer.android.com/studio/terms